# Reference a path outside the project directory

Tags: gradle

learning Gradle, and I am running into an issue. I'd like to add the JAR files from the TomcatEE directory to the compilation classpath, and the tomcatEE directory lives outside the project hierarchy on the file system. For example, the tomcatEE directory is "C:/servers/tomcatee/". I want to define a property "tomcarDir" and then add tomcatDir + '/lib/' to the build path, but Gradle insists on appending the project directory to the start. How do I specify an absolute path like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. In my gradle.properties file, I had the path to the tomcat directory enclosed in single quotes. By removing them, Gradle started treating it as an absoolute file path.